# Starting Docker-Engine on boot

Tags: docker, boot, systemd

When I restart my host, I want my docker engine to start on boot.

Is this possible?
Can anyone point me in right direction ?

My OS is RHEL 7.3 and 
my /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service fiel looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target firewalld.service

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
# Uncomment TasksMax if your systemd version supports it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this version.
#TasksMax=infinity
Restart=always
TimeoutStartSec=0
# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes
# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: This answer might help: https://serverfault.com/a/649835/119666

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes. You can use this command to enable automatic start of the docker service after startup:

```
 sudo systemctl enable /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

Comment: Seems it should be `sudo systemctl enable docker.service` on my centos.